# ASP.NET MVC get Exception message in Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have an action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    ...
    if (model.MyCondition == true)
        throw new Exception("MyMessage);
    ....
}
```

I'd like get the message "MyMessage" on the Ajax side :

```
onSuccess: function () {
...
},
onError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
//I'd like get "MyMessage" here
}
```

An idea how to do this ? When I check with the debugger I don't see my string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implementing an error attribute is a good way. Also, I usually don't throw the exception, but return a [status code](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=40132) according to error. You can write to your response stream and access in js via `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` :

```
if (model.MyCondition == true)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 406; // Or any other proper status code.
        Response.Write("Custom error message");
        return null;
    }
}
```

and in js:

```
...
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, errorThrown) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a ContentResult from your Action with a GET type action.

```
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult MyAction(String variablename)
{
    ...
    if (some_verification == true)
        return Content("MyMessage);
    ....
}
```

On your view page,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your controller/action url',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    data: { variablename: "value" },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error doing some work.');
    }
});
```

Comment: The question is get the string from the exception throw in the controller not way to change call the action

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this implementing a custom ErrorAttribute:

```
[NonAction]
protected void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{

    this.Session["ErrorException"] = filterContext.Exception;

    if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(MyException))
    {
        // Mark exception as handled
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        // ... logging, etc
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            /* Put your JSON format of the result */
            filterContext.Result = Json(filterContext.Exception.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            // Redirect
            filterContext.Result = this.RedirectToAction("TechnicalError", "Errors");
        }
    }
}
```

and then decorating my actions with it.

You can also override the OnException method of your controller, but I think that the custom attribute is way more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility could be to create a BaseController class where you override the Controller's `OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)` method and convert the exceptions into JSON for being able to easily process them from a JavaScript client.